# Notify the TObjectList when Object changed

Tags: delphi

Can the object of (TObjectList) know when some values of (TMyObject) was changed?

Some example:

```
TMyObject = class
  oName: string;
end;

TMyObjectList = class(TObjectList<TMyObject>)
end;

procedure Form1.Button1.Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Obj: TMyObject;
  List: TMyObjectList;
Begin
 List:= TMyObjectList.Create;
 Obj:= TMyObject.Create;
 List.Add(Obj);
 List[0].oName:= 'Test'; // here a want to know from var (List) when this object (Obj or List[0]) changed his value..
end;
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just added the `TObservableList<T>` type to Spring4D (feature/observablelist branch). It is mostly modeled after .NET and uses the INotifyPropertyChanged interface to attach its event handler to any objects that support it. This class has been part of DSharp for quite some time and is used in production. It might change a bit in the future and become full part of the library.

Here is a small example how to use it so you get an idea:

```
program Project60;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Spring,
  Spring.Collections,
  SysUtils;

type
  TNotifyPropertyChangedBase = class(TInterfaceBase, INotifyPropertyChanged)
  private
    fOnPropertyChanged: Event<TPropertyChangedEvent>;
    function GetOnPropertyChanged: IPropertyChangedEvent;
  protected
    procedure PropertyChanged(const propertyName: string);
  end;

  TMyObject = class(TNotifyPropertyChangedBase)
  private
    fName: string;
    procedure SetName(const Value: string);
  public
    property Name: string read fName write SetName;
  end;

  TMain = class
    procedure ListChanged(Sender: TObject; const item: TMyObject;
      action: TCollectionChangedAction);
  end;

{ TNotifyPropertyChangedBase }

function TNotifyPropertyChangedBase.GetOnPropertyChanged: IPropertyChangedEvent;
begin
  Result := fOnPropertyChanged;
end;

procedure TNotifyPropertyChangedBase.PropertyChanged(
  const propertyName: string);
begin
  fOnPropertyChanged.Invoke(Self,
    TPropertyChangedEventArgs.Create(propertyName) as IPropertyChangedEventArgs);
end;

{ TMyObject }

procedure TMyObject.SetName(const Value: string);
begin
  fName := Value;
  PropertyChanged('Name');
end;

{ TMain }

procedure TMain.ListChanged(Sender: TObject; const item: TMyObject;
  action: TCollectionChangedAction);
begin
  case action of
    caAdded: Writeln('item added ', item.Name);
    caRemoved, caExtracted: Writeln('item removed ', item.Name);
    caChanged: Writeln('item changed ', item.Name);
  end;
end;

var
  main: TMain;
  list: IList<TMyObject>;
  o: TMyObject;
begin
  list := TCollections.CreateObservableList<TMyObject>;
  list.OnChanged.Add(main.ListChanged);
  o := TMyObject.Create;
  o.Name := 'o1';
  list.Add(o);
  o := TMyObject.Create;
  o.Name := 'o2';
  list.Add(o);
  list[1].Name := 'o3';
  Readln;
end.
```

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing built in that can do what you ask. You will need to implement a notification mechanism yourself. This is the classic scenario for the [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

There are many implementations of this pattern already in existence. One obvious choice would be to use the implementation in Spring4D. Nick Hodges recent book, [More Coding in Delphi](https://leanpub.com/morecodingindelphi), includes a chapter on this pattern which I would recommend.

Comment: Thanks, this maybe help.  Found (OnNotify/Notify) methods in TObjectList, thats cant be used for solving my problem?

Comment: No. They are of no use to you. I'm sure you can see why from the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, @DavidHeffernan!

Answer (score -1):

Found the way, how to call method of TObjectList from TMyObject. Using TNotifyEvent in base Object.

Example:

```
TMyClass = class(TObject)
private
  FName: string;
  FOnNameEvent: TNotifyEvent;
  procedure SetName(value: string);
public
  property Name: string read FName write SetName;
  property OnNameEvent: TNotifyEvent read FOnNameEvent write FOnNameEvent;
end;

procedure TMyClass.SetName(value: string);
begin
  FName := value;
  if Assigned(FOnNameEvent) then
    FOnNameEvent(Self); 
end;

procedure MyNameEvent(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to MyListOfMyClassObjects.Count -1 do
    if Sender = MyListOfMyClassObjects.Item[i] then
    begin
      MessageBox(0, PChar(TMyClass(MyListOfMyClassObjects.Item[i]).Name), nil, MB_OK);
      break;
    end;
end;

procedure MyProc;
var
  MyObject: TMyClass;
begin
  MyObject := TMyClass.Create;
  MyObject.OnNameEvent := MyNameEvent;
  MyListOfMyClassObjects.Add(MyObject);
end;
```

Comment: Addition: procedure of event must be the method of some object.